# Prove that limit $\lim_{(x,y,z)\to{(0,0,\infty)}}(x^2 + y^2+z^2)^{7x^2y^2z^2}$ does not exist

Tags: limits

I need help with this limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y,z)\to{(0,0,\infty)}}(x^2 + y^2+z^2)^{7x^2y^2z^2}$$

Comment: A plan: What happens to the base when $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,\infty)$? What do you need to do the exponent to create indeterminate forms? That gives you clues  about how to let $(x,y,z)$ tend to its limit. You need a bit of variation to show that various paths lead to different limits. Or something else!

Comment: And. You probably know the drill by now. Show what happens in some special cases to dispel the thoughts that you just want somebody to do your homework. My previous comment may help you to show partial progress!

Comment: I have tried: x=x, y=x*k and z=l/x when x->0, cylindrical coordinates,... I've tried everything that I know. This was a question from exam that I had couple of days ago, not my homework and I've been trying to solve this since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where $x=y=z^{1/2}$, the limit becomes $$\lim_{z\to \infty}\left(\frac{2}{z}+z^2\right)^7$$ which diverges to $\infty$. In the case $x=y=1/z$, the limit becomes $$\lim_{z\to \infty} \left( \frac{2}{z^2}+z^2 \right)^{7/z^2}$$ For large z, the limit expression is of the form $\lim_{z\to \infty}z^{14/z^2} = 1$ Since different paths lead to different expressions, the limit does not exist.